# How to pass data into ejs without res.render?

Tags: node.js, redirect, passport.js, rendering, ejs

I want to send a variable value after succesful register but i have to do that without using res.render because i have some of flash messages if i want to show all of them i have to use res.redirect otherwise it does not work  for example :  who will try to register the flash message show "you cant use a password less than 6 character". How can i passs variable value to my ejs page for hide or display some of nav bar links according to after login or register or logout

```
// Here is my app.js file


// Config folder
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.port;
const dbUrl = process.env.dbUrl;

// İmport required npms
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const connectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const passport = require("passport");

const app = express();

// Passport Config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Db Connection And Permissions
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: process.env.useNewUrlParser,
    useUnifiedTopology: process.env.useUnifiedTopology,
    useCreateIndex: process.env.useCreateIndex
});
// Express-Session Settings , Permanenet Session
const mongoStore = connectMongo(session);

app.set('trustproxy', true)
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new mongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 86400000
    }
}));
// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// The Navbar Display Links According To Log in
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.session;
    if (userId) {
        res.locals = {
            displayLink: true
        }
    } else {
        res.locals = {
            displayLink: false
        }
    }
    next();
});

// Set ejs settings, middleware, static folders
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    next();
});

// Import Pages
const index = require("./routes");
const user = require("./routes/user");


// Routes
app.use("/", index);
app.use("/user", user);

app.listen(port, (err) => { if (err) throw err; console.log("No problem"); });



// Here is my user.js file


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passsport = require("passport");

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
// Users Routing Operations
// Get Requests 
// Login Page 
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/login");
});

// Register Page
router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/register");
});

// Post Requests
// After Finishing Register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, rptPassword } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    // Check required fields
    if (!name || !email || !password || !rptPassword) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Lütfen bütün alanları doldurunuz" });
    }
    // Check passwords match
    if (password !== rptPassword) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Şifreler eşleşmiyor" });
    }
    // Check password length
    if (password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Şifreniz en az 6 karakterden oluşmalı" });
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render("pages/register", {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            rptPassword
        });
    } else {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(async (user) => {
            if (!user) { // If user doesnt exist before
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
                req.body.password = hashedPassword;
                User.create(req.body, () => { });
                req.flash("success_msg", "Kayıt Tamamlandı");
                res.redirect("/user/register");
            } else {  // If user already exist
                errors.push({ msg: "Bu Email adresi kullanımda" })
                res.render("pages/register", {
                    errors,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    rptPassword
                });
                res.redirect("/user/register");
            }
        });
    }
});

// Login handle
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passsport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/user/login",
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});

// After Loging Out
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash("success_msg", "Çıkış Yaptınız");
    res.redirect("/user/login");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are already passing the variables in `res.redner`

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solutions for that is to use multiple query strings

and then you can handle the errors in the app.get functions like so

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
 const { name, email, password, rptPassword } = req.body;
// Check required fields
    if (!name || !email || !password || !rptPassword) {
        res.redirect('/register?error=error-1')
    }
```

then in the handle it like so

```
// Register Page
router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.error === 'error-1' )
    res.render("pages/register" ,{
msg: "Lütfen bütün alanları doldurunuz"
});
});
```

and so you can handle all errors by giving them unique code

Comment: Thank you so much ! this way very nice , i handled it with another a way , if the flash message will show to itself via redirect otherwise in all cases the app is going to do render by index.js ( router ) , after that i catch the if there is render and sending a variable  to the ejs and showing whatever i want by that variable. Even so thank you for everything !